# Resizing an Image with ObjectHandles

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

Does anyone know how to resize and move an Image with [ObjectHandles](http://code.google.com/p/flex-object-handles/downloads/list)

I need it to be as simple as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.objecthandles.com/examples

Comment: Can you provide an MXML which you can drag and drop an Image woth ObjectHandles?

Answer (score 0):

the examples are also included in the objecthandles files... try to import the examples... it should work fine. because I too based my project on that example files provided in the bundle